Page has a binding model issue, along with some strange behaviour in the OnPost method
Pref: I experienced some really strange behavior in ASP.NET Core. I started a MVC project, but I also included some Razor pages in the project.
When I attempt to bind the model and click the "Save" button, the input values are null or empty. The model is invalid and does not include the input values, it is completely empty. I checked all of the properties, and everything seems almost correct, but it is not binding the input values for Product.
[BindProperty]
public ProductViewModel Product { get; set; }

It's really strange that I created a second button, but it also calls the OnPost method for some reason... Similar case: removing the OnPost method and creating a method named OnPostSave does not get called, something went really wrong
<form method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input asp-for="Product.Name" class="form-control" type="text" />
    <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Test</button>
</form>

I suspect there may be an issue with the routing or a misconfiguration, but I'm not entirely sure. If you have any ideas or need more information, please let me know.
Thank you!
I attempted to debug the OnPost method, but I always received null or empty values. In another case regarding the button click event, I tried renaming the method and adding some validation, but it was unsuccessful.

Code is text and should be included in the question as text. MVC binding will either populate a function parameter, or a model property. Why are you trying to do both?

This is just a test, as almost nothing is worked, that's why.

From your shared screenshot, it seems the tag helper does not work. You can F12 in the browser and click the Elements tab to check the generated html, the correct html should be like:
<input type="text" id="Product_Name" name="Product.Name" value="">

Please add the following code in the top of your current Razor Pages:
@page
@model IndexModel

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

Or globally add it in Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml:
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers


Reference:
Managing Tag Helper scope

In Pages folder I don't have that file, that File is in the Views Folder, and in that there is a _ViewImports.cshtml the following line already there-> @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers | I added one more picture of my folder structure.

Hi @Smeth, Views/_ViewImports.cshtml only be available for views in Views folder instead of Pages folder. You must add such _ViewImports.cshtml file in Pages folder to make the tag helper work in razor pages.

As my answer said, If you do not want to add such _ViewImports.cshtml in Pages folder, you can add the import @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers  in the top of your current page.

Yes, you are right. Now I can see the parameter values, and it is also calling the OnPostSave method. Cool, Thank you! There is only one thing: it now needs 6 parameters instead of 3. But maybe it is a different question, but If could you look at that? I would appreciate it. I have attached the picture.

Hi @Smeth, It seems you need share your ProductDetailViewModel and Razor Pages code. It seems you need submit the form which contains Name,Price,Description and also a model named ProductDetail? What is your ProductDetail model which seems also contains Name,Price.Description property?

Your frontend page model is Product.xxx, which model is public ProductViewModel Product { get; set; } but your received model is ProductDetailViewModel . They are not match with each other.

Hi @Rena Based on the below comment, I changed the ProductViewModel to ProductDetailViewModel , maybe the rename can cause same problem. I bind this property->  public ProductDetailViewModel ProductDetail { get; set; }  Not sure what is other model..

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
